# Intersection and Curvature of Surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, curvature

a) Describe the intersection $(C)$ of sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the elliptic cylinder $x^2 + 2z^2 = 1$, and find out the total arc-length of this intersection.

b) Determine the points on the curve $(C)$, where the curvature have the maximum value.

I've been tackling this problem for quite awhile now, going through my notes, researching, reading my textbook but I have not gotten anything productive.  Any form of help or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two curves. They can be parametrized as follows.

$\gamma_1 :[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\gamma_1(t)=(\cos t,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t)$, and

$\gamma_2 :[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\gamma_2(t)=(\cos t,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t)$.

So $C=\gamma_1([0,2\pi])\cup \gamma_2([0,2\pi])$. Length of $\gamma_1$ is the same of $\gamma_2$, then the length of $C$ is
\begin{align*}
s&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(-\sin t)^2+2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t\right)^2}\mathrm dt\\
&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm dt\\
&=4\pi
\end{align*}

Also, it can be proved that $\gamma_1([0,2\pi])$ and $\gamma_2([0,2\pi])$ are circles of radius $r=1$ in the planes $z=y$ and $z=-y$, respectively. And  is a circle in the plane. Therefore, the curvature is constant, $\kappa=1$, for every point of $C$.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. I was wondering though if you'd be able to explain how you got your parametrized equations for the two curves? I understand why you do it, just not entirely how.  And one last thing, before you found the length of *C*, you took the derivative, why? By definition are we meant to?

Comment: Sorry for the constant questions, but for *b)* to find the points on *C* with the maximum curvature, how would I go about it? Would I have to individually make $\gamma_1 = 0$ and $\gamma_2 = 0$, isolate $t$ and find that coordinate?

Comment: Hello, there are many parametrizations, I prefer these ones that make easier to obtain the arc length, using trigonometric functions.
Also, since $C\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the set of points that satisfy both equations $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+2z^2=1$ it follows $y^2=z^2$ or $y=\pm z$. Then, $C$ is the set of points $(x,y,y)$ and $(x,y,-y)$ such that $x^2+2y^2=1$, also I knew this equation describes an ellipse in the plane, then I took the parametrization $x=\cos t, y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t$ $t\in[0,2\pi]$, I knew this parametrization works! Finally, I gave $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ as above

Answer (score 1):

From $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+2z^2=1$ it immediately follows that $z^2-y^2=0$, or $z=\pm y$. Conversely, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $z=\pm y$ imply $x^2+2z^2=1$. Therefore the intersection of $S^2$ and the elliptical cylinder coincides with the intersection of $S^2$ with the two planes $z=\pm y$, i.e. with the union of two unit circles intersecting at $(1,0,0)$. The total arc length is $4\pi$, and the curvature along these circles is of course constant.